# The complement of spanning trees is covered by a union of cycles

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Is it true that in any (connected) graph $G=(V,E)$, if $T$ is a spanning tree than its complement (edge-wise) may be covered by a union of disjoint cycles?

Here's a non-complete attempt to prove this claim:

- Each edge $e\in E\smallsetminus E(T)$ closes a single cycle if added to $T$
- The number of cycles in $E\smallsetminus E(T)$ of which $e$ is part of **is even** (I am not sure about that)
- There are no cycles within $T$
- Hence: taking the "sum" modulo 2 of all cycles in the graph (that is, a union with repetitions, discarding all edges which were counted an even number of times) produces a union of cycles which contains all edges of $E\smallsetminus E(T)$.

That's it; the missing part is the second bullet, which I'm not sure that is even true.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by complement. Since a spanning tree connects all vertices, removing it will disconnect the graph and in particular there will be no loops. But you can shrink a spanning tree to a vertex. What you get is a buffet of circles.

Comment: I mean its edge-complement. That is, the subgraph which contains all of $G$'s vertices, but whose edges are all of $G$'s edges which are not part of $T$. This does not always disconnect the graph.

Comment: What about $K_3$? The complement of a spanning tree is just an edge. (Of course that edge *is* part of an even number of cycles in $E\setminus E(T)$ :-) )

Comment: @Casteels: this is not contradicting the claim **or** my proof attempt. $K_3-T$ is an edge which is covered by a union of disjoint cycles ($K_3$ itself).

Comment: Ah ok. It wasn't clear to me where the cycles were "living"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $e \in E\smallsetminus E(T)$, let $C_e$ be the unique cycle in $T+e$. If you take the "sum" modulo $2$ of all cycle $C_e$ for all $e \in E\smallsetminus E(T)$, you get a subgraph $H$  of $G$ all whose components are Eulerian, hence  $H$ is the disjoint  union of cycles. Also,  $E\smallsetminus E(T) \subset E(H)$ since every $e \in E\smallsetminus E(T)$ is in exactly one cycle $C_e$ therefore it must be in "sum" modulo 2 (i.e $H$)

Comment: Oh, so mainly you claim my second bullet was irrelevant, and the rest of them are a proof already. Do you think the second bullet is true at all?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Your answer is perfect for my question. However, I am still curious about a proof for the second bullet alone.

Comment: I don't believe the second bullet is true. for example, start with a tree and add a cycle through all the vertices. Then, you will have the tree and the cycle and every edges not in the cycle is in exactly one cycle of the complement. Hence the number is not even.

Comment: Right... thanks.